# using quotes in sas macro filename pipe

Tags: macros, sas, filenames, dir, sas-macro

I am using the following Macro that uses filename pipe. But get an error saying invalid option name "dir", etc. I suspect it could be due to the quotes while defining filename and pipe. I guess it recognizes it as an option. I tried to remove the quote, removing %bquote and having just the double quote, but still keep getting the errors.

I am using Windows, but will also be running it remotely on Linux. Any thoughts would be deeply appreciated.

```
%macro setprogvar(dateval);
  %global date;

  %let date=&dateval;

  %put &date;
  %put &dateval;

  %let filepath = %bquote("C:\Research\SASDataSets\bulk all data &date");

  filename CDR_Bulk pipe "dir &filepath /a:-d-h-s /b /s";

%mend setprogvar;

%setprogvar(20100331);

***LOG************
1      filename CDR_Bulk pipe "dir &filepath /a:-d-h-s /b /s";
                           ---
                           23
ERROR 23-2: Invalid option name dir.

1   !  filename CDR_Bulk pipe "dir &filepath /a:-d-h-s /b /s";
                                          -
                                          23
ERROR 23-2: Invalid option name a.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filepath Macro variable needs wrapping in double-quotes as it contains spaces. But as your string is double-quoted, you need double-double-quotes...

```
filename CDR_Bulk pipe "dir ""&filepath"" /a:-d-h-s /b /s";
```

Comment: Thank you so much Chris and Quentin! That did the trick. Now I am running to another issue as I am going to run this unix...

Comment: Sure thank you. I didnt realize clicking on the tick mark does the trick as I was trying to click on the up arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing %bquote in your macro to %str().

%Str() works during macro compile time, and should mask the double quote marks.

HTH